# how to use @NameLookUp formula in lotus notes in Java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

can anyone please tell how to use @NameLookUp formula in lotus Notes.I need it to retrieve the  internet address from the Canonical Form of the user.I could not find any example in the net.It would be of great help if an example is given.

Comment: use evaluate to execute @formula in Java: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EXAMPLES_EVALUATE_METHOD_JAVA.html

Comment: thanks for the reply..i am using the formula as
String userName="CN=sam peat/OU=QUO/O=SCT@SCT";
Vector vec=m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([Exhaustive];\""+ userName + "\"; \"InternetAddress\")");

this is not retrieving any details.i am not getting where i am going wrong..plz help..

Comment: Try userName without "@SCT".

Comment: hey knut..it works after removing the @SCT part..thanks

Comment: hi knut..can u post your suggestion as answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Evaluate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_EVALUATE_METHOD_JAVA.html) to execute @NameLookup formula in Java.

Remove "@SCT" from parameter username `String userName="CN=sam peat/OU=QUO/O=SCT@SCT"` in your example.

Answer (score 3):

```
@NameLookup([Exhaustive];@UserName;"InternetAddress")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..i am using the formula as
String userName="CN=sam peat/OU=QUO/O=SCT@SCT";
Vector vec=m_session.evaluate("@NameLookup([Exhaustive];\""+ userName + "\"; \"InternetAddress\")");

this is not retrieving any details.i am not getting where i am going wrong..plz help..

Comment: check first if @NameLookup([Exhaustive];@UserName;"InternetAddress") is working for the current User

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Domino 8 above, you should be able to do this:

```
String address = "";
Directory d = session.getDirectory();
DirectoryNavigator dn = d.lookupNames("$Users","CN=sam peat/OU=QUO/O=SCT","InternetAddress",false);
```

Then you can use the [methods of the DirectoryNavigator class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESDIRECTORYNAVIGATOR_CLASS_JAVA.html) (i.e. `findFirstMatch()`, `getFirstItemValue()`), to get the returned value.